# Optional integer parameter defaults to zero alhough it is assigned as -1

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf service and the client will consume this WCF service by a custom generated proxy which will be given to the client.

```
[OperationContract]
string GetData(int value);
```

So now i have added a new optional parameter of type int to one of my WCF contracts which should default to -1. I haven't given the updated proxies to the client and now if the client calls the contract the new optional parameter is being assigned to 0 rather than -1

```
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value, int pre = -1);
```

How come it is not getting the default value that was assigned to it which is -1. Is it expected to work like this ?

[image]

Comment: Try Creat overload without second argument with call to original method passing -1

Comment: It says no overloaded method takes two arguments although in intellisense it showing two overloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't given the updated proxies to the client

Yes, this is expected. When you added the parameter without updating the client, WCF automatically filled in the missing value from the client call using the default value for the type. It doesn't know about the default value declared in your class.

One reason it's preferred to declare your WCF contract using interfaces instead of classes is that interfaces more closely match what WCF supports. You wouldn't have even been able to declare the method with a default value for a parameter in an interface. :)

An alternative is to implement defaults the way that we used to have to do it in regular C# code before default parameters showed up: by implementing overloads for the method. I.e. the call site will call a method that actually doesn't use the parameter. In this scenario, the callee determines the default value.

(This approach is still useful in regular C# code, for that matter, where you want to be able to change the default value of a parameter without changing callers).

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments are not supported in WCF interfaces.